# Question based on code golf mod - divisor sequence not in OEIS

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Interestesd in the aymptotics of [this series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90437/score-tarzans-olympic-vine-swinging-routine) - semes like is is related to sum of divisors:

```
With[{a = N[(# Log@# + (2 EulerGamma - 2) #)] & /@ 
Range@#}, (Take[aa, #] - a)/a] &[10^5] // ListPlot
```

gives this plot

[image]

where `aa` is list of function as described in OP to $10^5$
 (similar plor for $p_n$ since only to $10^5$).

Since it seems to $\sim n \log n+O(n \log n) $, does it cross $p_n$ line infintitely often (where $p_n$ is $n$th prime)?